# How set WebRequest stream share mode to share_read?

Tags: c#, webrequest

I use the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16066106/7206675) to upload large files to ftp site.
As the file is uploaded to the server I go to the server with the RDP and can not open it because it is being used by another process.

My question is, can I set the file sharing mode so that I can read the file while writing? I want to read the uploaded file while it is being written.

```
FileStream fs = null;
Stream rs = null;

try 
{
    string file = "D:\\RP-3160-driver.zip";
    string uploadFileName = new FileInfo(file).Name;
    string uploadUrl = "ftp://ftp.Sitename.com/tempFiles/";
    fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    string ftpUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadUrl, uploadFileName);
    FtpWebRequest requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl) as FtpWebRequest;
    requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usernam", "password");
    rs = requestObj.GetRequestStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8092];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
       rs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    rs.Flush();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("File upload/transfer Failed.\r\nError Message:\r\n" + ex.Message, "Succeeded", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally 
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
    }

    if (rs != null)
    {
        rs.Close();
        rs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I added FileShare.ReadWrite to the FileStream:

```
string file = "D:\\RP-3160-driver.zip";
string uploadFileName = new FileInfo(file).Name;
string uploadUrl = "ftp://ftp.Sitename.com/tempFiles/";

using (FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    string ftpUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", uploadUrl, uploadFileName);
    FtpWebRequest requestObj = FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl) as FtpWebRequest;
    requestObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    requestObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usernam", "password");
    using (Stream rs = requestObj.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(rs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not help

Comment: I update the answer, try now... Seems to be working for me.

Comment: Does not help for me. You're dealing with the stream of the file instead of dealing with the stream of the request.

Comment: You want to read the uploaded file while it is being written?

Comment: Yes, this is a large file, so I want to start reading it while writing.

Comment: You can google `producer/consumer pattern` to do it like you want. Reading and writting at the same time.